# "App deployment failed. Please try again" when deployed an app with SDK8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to Deploy an App for Windows Phone 8 using SDK8.0 (Emulator XVGA 512Mb), but I got an error "App deployment failed. Please try again" after screen "`Windows phone OS is starting`" abou 5 minutes.

I'm using Sony Vaio Eg32fx that supported virtualization,Windows 8 enterprise x64, Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, SDK8.0, I have turned on V-Hyper and Virtualization in BIOS, turn off any Antivirus programs and Windows Firewall.

When I tried to run the command below:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0\xde.exe" -vhd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Emulation\Images\Flash.vhd"
```

, the Windows Phone 8 Screen show. That means My Computer can run a Virtual Windows Phone OS, but In Visual Studio, I chose  Emulator XVGA 512Mb , It failed.

I followed this topic but no way

http://moustafa-arafa.blogspot.com/2013/03/fix-it-application-deployment-failed.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

but no way to fix.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator may not work when its dedicated requirements are not perfectly matched.
[Emulator Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

You can always try deploying an app by selecting 'Device' in the emulator which will actually deploy the app on your phone and you can test it out.

note: Make sure you're using the right version of app which is to be deployed in its righteous OS version.

Answer (score -1):

Try grant all permission level to all user for your virtual machines in this path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Emulation\Images
```